# using val method to set properties from Object

Tags: jquery

I am confused about how to properly use `val` method. My book says `$(v).val(obj[name]);` will set the value of the field from the value of the property. However, I am not clear about what this means. Here is the code I am having trouble understanding. It is designed to repopulate a form's fields back to its original values. I would appreciate a step by step explanation as I am still very new to jQuery. Thanks

```
fromObject:function(obj){
    $.each(this.find(':input'),function(i,v){
        var name = $(v).attr('name');
        if (obj[name]){
            $(v).val(obj[name]); //does this set the property as the value?
        } else {
            $(v).val('');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation

Comment: Basically: **GET VALUE:** `$(v).val()` and **SET VALUE:** `$(v).val(<anyValue>)`

Comment: It can be as simple as `this.find(':input').val(function() {
  return obj[this.name] || '';
})`

Comment: @ArunPJohny i think your code is confusing him more :)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not familiar with the bracket notation for accessing an objects properties.

Suppose I have a form data object like `obj = {name:"bob"}`

We usually access the name like `obj.name; // we get bob`

It can be done like `obj['name']` as well. This is used when the property name is not a proper variable name, for example

```
obj = { "contacts[]": ["bob","john"] }

obj['contacts[]'] // we get ["bob","john"]
obj.contacts[] // syntax error
```

or when the property name you want to access is dynamic, like your case: You want to access the property corresponding to the value of name property. We can't use the `.` notation here because we don't know what the property name (value of name attribute ) is going to be.

So the confusing line of code: `$(v).val(obj[name]);` is a mix of both:

first we assign the value of name property to a variable `name`.
When the value of name property is "contacts[]", `$(v).val(obj[name]);` is equivalent to `$(v).val(obj["contacts[]"]);` which evaluates to   `$(v).val(["bob","john"]);`

Comment: Thanks T J, why would you even add brackets in a property name that cannot be accessed using dot notation?

Comment: @st4rgut it's common when you work with technologies like JSP where the form is directly submitted to a java servlet. It's treated as an array or something, I've seen people doing it. Maybe I should've used `first-name` instead of `contacts[]`. That gives an error with `.` notation as well. People will do `<input type="text" name="first-name"/>`!

Answer (score 0):

**$(v).val(obj[name])**;

set the value of specific DOM element "v" and you can also get the value as **$(v).val();**